# How to install Ubuntu on a laptop with a portable external Hard Drive?

Tags: boot, system-installation, hard-drive, external-hdd

**System**

OS:Windows 10

Laptop: Lenovo X1 Carbon gen7

**Description**

I want install Linux Ubuntu on portable external Hard Drive USB 2.0(Seagate FreeAgent GoFlex[500GB]). I have already booted Ubuntu 20.04 from a Usb and clicked try now. My external hard drive is partially filled(50%), I need to keep all files., but I want to safely boot from the external hard drive and not disturb the internal drive or windows, since this is my main computer.

I want the Ubuntu install to be completely separate from my internal drive. Can somebody guide me on how to do this. I have tried looking for tutorials,but I have only found ones for desktop.

Comment: Machine Specs:
CPU: Intel i5-8265U
RAM:8.oo GB
GPU: Intel UHD 620

Comment: Yes, I can try to help you. Do you want to boot the drive only in UEFI mode or only BIOS mode or both? Do you want to 'do it yourself', or do you want a convenient way (to use a 'pre-fabricated' system)? Depending on your answer, I will suggest what i think is the best method for you.

Comment: @sudodus The hard drive is 50% full, just made an edit. srry

Comment: @sudodus I want to boot it in a way that is safe and easy. I don't know what UEFI is. Could you recommend me one.

Comment: Editing partition tables and installing operating systems is **always risky**. This means that you must backup your data to another drive (or other location) before you start, or simply get another drive (and keep this USB 2 HDD for backup purposes).

Comment: Do you want to boot into Ubuntu from your external drive in more than one computer? If only one computer, [**this link**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/942312#942312) has a good (and detailed) description. It is important to unplug, disconnect or otherwise disable the internal drive in order to avoid touching it during the installation.

Comment: What if I want to only use 200 gb of my Hard Drive. I need to shrink it right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110771/discussion-between-sudodus-and-unloading-gnat).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Full Install of Ubuntu to External Drive

- Back up Data on external drive.
- Determine Windows 10 boot mode. Type `System Information` in Windows Start panel. Under "BIOS Mode" it will say if Windows is Legacy or UEFI.
- If UEFI mode unplug your internal drive, or the drive will try to use Windows EFI partition.
- Boot a Ubuntu 20.04 Live USB in the same mode as Windows boot mode. Plug in the External drive.
- Use GParted to reduce the existing External HDD Data partition to make room for Ubuntu. 200GB should be plenty.
- If UEFI mode create a 500MB FaT32 partition.
- Create an ext4 partition in the remaining empty space.
- Click the Install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS icon, Select Language, Keyboard, Wireless, Normal Installation, Install third Party...
- Select `Something else`.
- Under "Device for boot loader installation" select the external drive. This is important.
- Select the new ext4 partition and click change, Select `use as Ext4`, `Mount point = /` then OK. select format this partition,
- If UEFI, select the new FAT32 partition and click change, Select `Use as: EFI System Partition` then OK. Select format this partition.
- Click Install now. Confirm partitions to be formatted if asked, click continue.
- Select your location.
- Insert your name, computer name, username, password and select if you want to log in automatically or require a password. - Click "Continue".
- After install, if internal drive was unplugged, plug it back in.
- Boot the external drive and run `sudo update-grub` to add Windows to it's boot menu.

Note:

This drive will only boot in the mode it was created in. If you need to boot both BIOS and UEFI we can modify the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

If it was me, I would use your internal hard drive for the operating systems (Ubuntu 20.04 only needs about 25 gb or more) and use the external for files.